# Liferay dynamic data lists

Tags: date, timestamp, liferay, dynamic-data-list

I'm using liferay (6.1) to make my portlets and right now I'm using dynamic data lists to define my data definition.

Is there anyway to add new **Data definition fields**?

Instead of the calendar date I want to add hours, minutes and seconds in the format of `hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to extend DDL available field types.

DDL Field types are hardcoded into the code (take a look at com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.storage.FieldConstants), so you'll need to use the ext-plugin to change that; also, the JSPs are a little hairy.

So, while possible, I would expect the task to be quite complex.